# How can I create an Object that includes undetermined fields

Tags: java, json, generics, serialization

I am creating a comparing service, that compare two objects and generate results including what is the different part. The comparing result object will be mapped to a JSON and return to REST service.

```
public class CompareResult {

private final String errorCode;
private final String codeName;
private final Map<String, T> compareResult;

setter, getter
}
```

Since the object I will compare is complicated, and it may contain many difference bags, for example: **ObjectToBeCompared** object include 3 fields which are three other object 1,2,3. If the object 2 has difference between **objectToBeCompared1** and **objectToBeCompared2**, then I want to copy over the object 2 into the **compareResult** field:

```
 compareResult.put("Object2InObjectToBeCompared1", ObjectToBeCompared1.Object2),   
 compareResult.put("Object2InObjectToBeCompared2", ObjectToBeCompared2.Object2)
```

, and the **T** might be object 1 or object 3.

I know this might has something to do with the generic type, but, I just don't know how to implement this. Simply speaking, in the field that I defined in the **CompareResult** class, the **compareResult** is a *Map*, and the **T** could be any object.  Can I use *Map*, if so, when I use the **objectMapper** to map from object to JSON String, will that cause any problem?

Answer (score 0):

> compareResult is a Map, and the T could be any object

Since you don't want to put any restrictions on type, I think it would be a great idea to drop generics.

You can do something like

```
private final Map<String, Object> compareResult;
```

---

The answer to your second question would be no, the `ObjectMapper` should work fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, so when I create the CompareResult object, in the member variable, I can create any Map like Map<"object1", object1>, Map<"object2", object2>. Since I am not the owner of object 1 and object2, I do not have to make any change, right ?  and when I serialize the CompareResult into JSON String, I just use mapper.writeValueAsString(CompareResult) ?

Comment: I mean, If I want to put the Object1, Object 2 as the value of any string in the map. I dont have to do anything on the Object1 or 2 itself right ? because I can not change them. I am not the owner of Object that I compare.

Comment: You just need references of those objects. The map shall store only references and the objects will not be changed. Serialization also would not change the objects.